# How to get network profile username?

Tags: feature-request, api-v2

I was thinking I could just get the username from the response of /users/{ids}/associated (where {ids} is the not-site-specific id). But then realised that it returns only network_user (even though we have filters now ?!?!)

Would it be possible to have a network /users/{ids} and network /me route, that will fetch the  network profile details. This would make it easier to get a user's overall profile.

Or instead just have /user/{ids}/associated return a full user, and let filters do what they do best.

Comment: Don't forget that the network profile isn't actually separate from the other accounts - it is simply synched with one of the other accounts. So all the API would need to do is indicate which account was currently chosen.

Comment: Yeah, having the user name and aggregated reputation information in a single query would be super convenient.